# what this value mean in address with ' symbol

Tags: windbg

I am trying to investigate an access violation issue in code. As you can see some of the value for address contains apostrophe character (like in **7fb`80246000**).

```
0:000> !address -summary  

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal  
Free                                    424      7fb`80246000 (   7.982 Tb)           99.78%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tick mark (grave accent) is just used to separate the lower 4 bytes from the higher 4 bytes of a 64-bit number.

```
7fb`80246000
```

is the same as

```
0x7fb80246000
```

It is purely for visual aesthetics (making the value easier to parse by humans).